# How can I bind object id from *ngFor item in Angular Select? At the moment, the select bind the same value as interpolation do.

Tags: angular

I have a list listSiteTriage. I would like to bind to the controller selected value.

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedSite" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
                  <option *ngFor="let site of listSiteTriage" >{{site.Intitule}}</option>
                </select>
```

controller:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'xxx',
 templateUrl: './xxx.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./xxx.component.scss']
 })
 export class Travaux implements OnInit , OnChanges {

 listSiteTriage: any[];
 site: any;


 } 
  onChange(){
  console.log(this.selectedSite);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove [ngValue]

```
<select [(ngModel)]="site" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
         <option *ngFor="let site of listSiteTriage" >{{site.Intitule}}</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are `iterator` and the `ngModel` variables are both named as `site` rename it to be different (for instance `selectedSite`)

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedSite" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
      <option *ngFor="let site of listSiteTriage" [ngValue]="site.Id">{{site.Intitule}}</option>
</select>

import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'xxx',
 templateUrl: './xxx.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./xxx.component.scss']
 })
 export class Travaux implements OnInit , OnChanges {

listSiteTriage: any[];
selectedSite: any = 1;

onChange(){
      console.log(this.site);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you are setting the `ngValue=site` it will be the complete object and you can have the full object in the `site`